# Leveling countertop for quartz

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-counters, countertops, quartz

I had a Formica countertop that originally had an edge with a raised bar. I removed the Formica and the raised bar - it was made up of a stack of 2x4s that I removed - the last 2x4 that I left was about 3/4" higher than the cabinet tops so I laid down 3/4" plywood. This worked well but I noticed on one side the 2x4 is a little out of level so the entire surface isn't perfectly flat.

Is it possible to use something like self leveling floor patch compound to try to smooth out the surface for the quartz or should I just let the countertop guys use shims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countertop manufacturer/seller will have requirements for the support of the countertop material that say it must have support every X inches, and that any overhang over Y inches must be properly supported, etc.  You don't need something like a leveling compound to support 100% of the underside, so that's a bit of overkill.

A friend of mine tried to place the propper supports for a new countertop, and did what looked like a good job, but the first think the installer did is rip out a lot of his support work so they could do it on their own.  They very much had a "don't trust anything that I didn't do myself" attitude.  Of course its a single example, but I'm sure the installer is planning on leveling everything properly.  Might as well just let them do it.